# Model object attribute not change without assign to variable

Tags: python, django, django-models

I try here to change title but this not work.

[image]

but when assign object to variable, change works.

[image]

> I need any one explain why it work when I assign object to variable
> and why not work when access it directly?

Comment: You need to post actual text, not screenshots of text, as per the [ask] page.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because using the slice operator (`[0]` in this case) will always execute a new query, so none of your changes will be reflected.

That is why your second example where you save the result of `project[0]` works, because you are preventing the reevaluation of the queryset by saving the result first.

Comment: this explain why id change every time access it directly, thanks alot for your help <3